# Stored procedure not running correctly with dynamic sql text

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

For some reason my stored procedure is executed without any error from the code-behind in C# but it is not deleting anything at all that the stored procedure has written. I have all the correct parameters and everything. I ran the query from SQL Server with all the same parameters from the C# code and it works perfectly. I don't get why it works when I run from SQL Server but it doesn't work when I run it from my C# code in Visual Studio.

Here is my C# code that is passing the data through to the stored procedure.

```
string reportType = "PostClaim";
string GRNBRs = "925','926','927";
string PUNBRs = "100','100','100";
string beginningDates = "20120401";
string endDates= "20120430";

try
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionInfo);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("RemoveReport", conn);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportType", reportType);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GRNBR", GRNBRs);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PUNBR", PUNBRs);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE1", beginningDates);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE2", endDates);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 360;
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    //something went wrong
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
}
```

Here is my stored procedure. It's executing with dynamic SQL text.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveReport] (
    @ReportType NVARCHAR(20),
    @GRNBR VARCHAR(4000),
    @PUNBR VARCHAR(4000),
    @DATE1 DATETIME,
    @DATE2 DATETIME
)
AS

DECLARE @SQLTEXT VARCHAR(4000)
BEGIN

SET @SQLTEXT = 'DELETE FROM TestingTable
            WHERE Report='''+@ReportType+''' AND
            PUNBR IN ('''+@PUNBR+''') AND
            [Group] IN ('''+@GRNBR+''') AND
            StartedAt BETWEEN '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DATE1,121)+'''
            AND '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DATE2,121)+''''

PRINT @SQLTEXT  <---I'll print this out to show you what exactly it is executing.
EXECUTE (@SQLTEXT)
END
```

Here is what the `PRINT @SQLTEXT` is running:

```
DELETE FROM MonthlyReportSchedule
WHERE Report='PostClaim' AND
      PUNBR IN ('100','100','100') AND
      [Group] IN ('925','926','927') AND
      StartedAt BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-30'
```

When I actually go into SQL Server to run this query, it works perfectly. But why does it not work on when executed from the C# code. Any help?

Comment: To add a little more detail to M.Ali's answer. From c# passing in single quotes in parameters will be modified to avoid SQL injection, which is why it breaks.

Comment: Also using SQL profiler would have shown you the resulting code, and shown you what was happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid concatenating parameters to your sql, use parameterised query,

Try this...

Just noticed that you have some comma delimited lists in params.....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveReport]
    @ReportType NVARCHAR(20),
    @GRNBR VARCHAR(4000),
    @PUNBR VARCHAR(4000),
    @DATE1 DATETIME,
    @DATE2 DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQLTEXT NVARCHAR(MAX);

   Declare @GRNBR_xml xml,@PUNBR_xml xml;

  SET @GRNBR_xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@GRNBR, ',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>';
  SET @PUNBR_xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@PUNBR, ',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>';


SET @SQLTEXT = N'DELETE FROM TestingTable
            WHERE Report = @ReportType
              AND PUNBR IN (select r.value(''.'',''varchar(max)'') as item
                            from @PUNBR_xml.nodes(''//root/r'') as records(r)) 
              AND [Group] IN (select r.value(''.'',''varchar(max)'') as item
                              from @GRNBR_xml.nodes(''//root/r'') as records(r)) 
              AND StartedAt BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLTEXT
                     ,N'@ReportType NVARCHAR(20) , @GRNBR_xml xml,
                       @PUNBR_xml xml,@DATE1 DATETIME,@DATE2 DATETIME'
                      ,@ReportType
                      ,@GRNBR_xml
                      ,@PUNBR_xml
                      ,@DATE1
                      ,@DATE2
END
```

**Note**

Make sure you pass the comma delimited list as `925,926,927` and not as `'925','926','927'`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in order to be executed

```
da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will execute a call to your stored procedure.

good luck